# Need to add a node to an XML file in VBA without overwriting older node

Tags: xml, vba, nodes

I have a XML that I'm importing a set of notes and associating it to the current date and time node (Date NoteD) for example:

```
<Serial SerialN="3s">
<Model>3m</Model>
<Assigned>3a</Assigned>
<DateA>7/3/2014</DateA>
<DateR>N/A</DateR>
<Notes>
    <Date NoteD="7/19/2014 07:58:42 PM">
         <Entry>This is a test</Entry>
    </Date>
</Notes>
</Serial>
```

I want to add another entry with a new current date and time so it appears like this:

```
<Notes>
    <Date NoteD="7/19/2014 07:58:42 PM">
         <Entry>This is a test</Entry>
    </Date>
    <Date NoteD="7/19/2014 09:45:00 PM">
         <Entry>This is another test</Entry>
    </Date>
</Notes>
```

Problem is that it keeps overwriting the date but adding another entry like this:

```
<Notes>
    <Date NoteD="7/19/2014 09:45:00 PM">
         <Entry>This is a test</Entry>
         <Entry>This is another test</Entry>
    </Date>
</Notes>
```

Here is my code:

```
 Set x = objDom.SelectSingleNode("//Serial[@SerialN='" & TextBox1.Text & "']/Notes")
 Set Datee = objDom.createElement("Date")
 x.appendChild Datee


 Set n = objDom.SelectSingleNode("//Serial[@SerialN='" & TextBox1.Text & "']/Notes/Date")
 Set Notes = objDom.createAttribute("NoteD") 
 Notes.NodeValue = Now
 n.setAttributeNode Notes


Set t = objDom.SelectSingleNode("//Serial[@SerialN='" & TextBox1.Text & "']/Notes/Date[@NoteD='" & Notes.NodeValue & "']")
Set Note = objDom.createElement("Entry")
t.appendChild Note
Note.Text = TextBox5.Text
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd block of your code should've been like this :

```
Set n = objDom.SelectSingleNode("//Serial[@SerialN='" & TextBox1.Text & "']/Notes/Date")
Set Notes = objDom.createAttribute("NoteD") 
Notes.NodeValue = Now
Datee.setAttributeNode Notes
```

Add the attribute to newly created `<Date>` element instead of existing one.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
With xmlDoc.DocumentElement.appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement("type"))

    .appendChild (xmlDoc.createTextNode(vbCrLf))

    With .appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement("domaine"))

     .Text = ms

     End With

    With .appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement("phrase"))

     .Text = cle

     End With

 End With
```